A certain subfield of $\mathbb{C}(x,y)$
Let $A=\mathbb{C}(x+y,xy)$, the subfield of symmetric polynomials with respect to the involution $\alpha: (x,y) \mapsto (y,x)$.
Denote $G_A=\{w \in \mathbb{C}(x,y) \ | \ \mathbb{C}(x+y,xy,w)=A(w)=\mathbb{C}(x,y) \}$; since $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):A]=2$, we have $G_A=\mathbb{C}(x,y)-A$.

I am looking for a possible ('minimal' or 'non-minimal') subset $S \subsetneq G_A$ with the following property:
If a subfield $R \subsetneq \mathbb{C}(x,y)$ is such that $S \subseteq G_R:=\{w \in \mathbb{C}(x,y) \ | \ R(w)=\mathbb{C}(x,y) \}$, then $R \subseteq A$.
Especially, is the following $S \subsetneq G_A$ satisfies the above property? $S=\{x^{2i}y^{2j+1} \}_{i,j \geq 0} \cup \{x^{2k+1}y^{2l} \}_{k,l \geq 0} \cup \{x^{2m}\}_{m \geq 1}\ \cup \{y^{2n}\}_{n \geq 1}$.

I have tried to take a 'minimal' $S$, avoiding sums of monomials, but taking all monomials needed; perhaps I am wrong.
Similar questions appear in MSE i and ii, and in MO
iii and iv.
Thank you very much!
Edit: Maybe it is easier to require in the property that the subring $R$ has the following form: $R=\mathbb{C}(u,v)$, for some algebraically independent $u,v \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Myabe there is a counterexample to my question, not having a nice form as the forms of the counterexamples of my previous questions.
